# Как открыть порт в настройках роутера Интеркросс ICxETH5670NE

Tags: ip, роутер, порты

[image: снимок экрана настроек с пустыми полями]

Подскажите,пожалуйста, что нужно ввести в этих полях, чтобы открыть 7777 на конкретно на данном примере, раньше был роутер тп-линк все легко было, а тут интеркросс и не получается. Вот, что вписал:

[image: снимок экрана с заполненными настройками]